# com/ibm/etools/ejbdeploy/EjbDeploy error websphere 7

Tags: ant, websphere-7

I got the build working by adding user.install.root and set up the profile value in taskdef,

```
<taskdef name="wasejbjar" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy" classpath="D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar;D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\;" >
</taskdef> 
  <wasejbjar inputJar="${build.root.dir}/ejbtemp/${undeployed.ejb.name}-TMP.jar" wasHome="D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\"  workingDirectory="${build.root.dir}/ejbtemp" outputJar="${build.lib.dir}/${undeployed.ejb.name}.jar" classpathref="all.ejb.path" noValidate="false" noWarnings="false" noInform="true" trace="false" quiet="false"/>
```

But even now I get the following error as:

> [wsejbdeploy] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/etools/ejbdeploy/EJBDeploy [wsejbdeploy] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing arbitrary JARs from `WAS_HOME/plugins` is not supported. I believe the supported use of the Ant task is to use the `WAS_HOME/bin/ws_ant` script. (Unfortunately, it's a quite old version of Ant.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and resolved it. I marked the jar file as _old, which resolved the issue.

The path is as follows, D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\lib\ibmorbtools_old.jar.

This is because in one of the forum, i read that the ibmorbtools.jar in Java conflict with websphere.

Thanks for all.